# Reboot debian machine via script from another machine in local network

Tags: shell-script, ssh, reboot

Hi I need to reboot "machine A" from "machine B". Both are connected to local network. Basically I need a simple script on "machine B" that does it. IP adresses are static.
I have installed sshpass and I can run a script on "A" from "B".
But there is a problem with reboot, command cannot be ran without sudo. Command systemctl reboot -i can be ran without sudo, but if I write a simple script that does this, an error with failed to se wall message appears in the ssh console.

Thanks for any advices.
Petr

Comment: Just create a suid script which call reboot (and maybe some other command, e.g. notify users, closing some useful programs). Then call such script from ssh

Comment: Can you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ssh -tt remoteHost sudo shutdown -r +3 'Please log off ... reboot imminent'
```

You need one of the following three criteria

- that `/sbin/shutdown` is a permitted action in the `sudoers` file for your account
- equivalence to allow you to `ssh` to the target system as root
- the ability to enter a password for `sudo` on demand

My actual command when I can *guarantee* no-one is using the remote machine:

```
ssh root@remoteHost shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using systemd:

```
$ systemctl --host root@remoteHost reboot
```